# Яндекс.карты событие "перетаскивание карты"

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как используя API Яндекс.карт отреагировать на событие "центр карты сместился". Если ли такое готовое или по .mouseup отлавливать костылями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/Map.xml#event-boundschange

люблю я хэшкод, иногда достаточно спросить и ответ находится сам :)